# PHP/JS: Echoing several variables without losing their value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

The JS/Ajax function I have built submits without a button click or page refresh. The function gets the values of the input field and with php echoed out the results. But everytime a variable is echoed the next variable erases the value of the previous one. How can avoid this? [EXAMPLE](http://google.com)

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer = null; 
    var dataString;   
      function submitForm(){
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
           url: "index.php",
           data: dataString,
           success: function(result){
                         $('#special').html('<p>' +  $('#resultval', result).html() + '</p>');
                                           }
                 });
                 return false; }

    $('#contact_name').on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
          var name = $("#contact_name").val();
    dataString = 'name='+ name;
    });

     $('#email').on('keyup', function() {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
     var name = $("#email").val();
     dataString = 'name='+ name;
     });

     $('#phone').on('keyup', function() {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
     var name = $("#phone").val();
     dataString = 'name='+ name;
     });

     $('#address').on('keyup', function() {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
     var name = $("#address").val();
     dataString = 'name='+ name;
     });

     $('#website').on('keyup', function() {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
     var name = $("#website").val();
     dataString = 'name='+ name;
     });


 }); 
</script>
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contact_form" name="form4"> 
     <div class="row">  
      <div class="label">Contact Name *</div> <!-- end .label --> 
        <div class="input"> 
          <input type="text" id="contact_name" class="detail" name="contact_name" value="<?php $contact_name ?>" />  
          <div id="special"><span id="resultval"></span></div>  
        </div><!-- end .input--> 
     </div><!-- end .row --> 
     <div class="row">  
      <div class="label">Email Address *</div> <!-- end .label --> 
       <div class="input"> 
        <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="<?php $email ?>" />  
        <div id="special"><span id="resultval"></span></div> 
       </div><!-- end .input--> 
     </div><!-- end .row --> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `append()` method:

```
success: function(result){
        $('#special').append('<p>' + result + '</p>');
}
```

as you have set similar classes to the inputs you can minify your code:

```
 $('.detail').on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var name = $(this).val();
    dataString = 'name='+ name;
    timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
 });
```

note that IDs *must* be unique and repetitively requesting data from the server is not efficient.

Comment: Thank you! One question about the IDs: How can I make the IDs unique?

Comment: @cholomanCoding you are welcome, they should not be similar, for example you have two elements with id of `#special`, you can change them to `#special1` and `#special2` or simply use a class like `.special`.

Comment: Oh alright. So if I change the divs to  `<div id="special1"></div>` and `<div id="special2"></div>`  will i have to add this too:  `$('#special1').append('<p>' + result + '</p>');` 
`$('#special2').append('<p>' + result + '</p>');`

Comment: @jonthecoder2346 they can be selected this way, `$('#special1, #special2').append('<p>' + result + '</p>')`

Comment: @Raminson Thank you all, Specially Ramison! for the great answer and comments. Append: so if change the value of an input, it will show the old value, is there away to avoid this?

Comment: @cholomanCoding you are welcome, append() appends the data to prevous contents but if you replace it with `html()` it clears all the children and appends the new result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is caused by using same ids for multiple elements.

Ids should be unique but in case there are same ids only the first element with such id is selected.

Comment: +1 I am new learner to all this. How can I make the IDs unique?

Comment: You make the ids unique by using a different id for for each element. In your form example you can use special_email, special_contact_name, etc...